# Глагол, обозначающий действие, связанное с сущ. «архитектура»

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, переводы

Какой глагол в русском языке обозначает слово, связанное с существительным **архитектура**: «архитектурить», «архитектуировать»? Иными словами, какое слово соответствует английскому *to architect*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

В современном русском литературном языке **нет** однокоренного существительному *архитектура* глагола, поэтому для обозначения того же смысла, что передает английский *to architect*, используются **либо слова с другим корнем, либо словосочетания**.

Например, рассмотрим предложение:

> As we begin to **architect** these systems, often the reality is too hard to handle.

В этом контексте *architect* можно перевести как *разрабатывать (системы), создавать, проектировать*.

Если речь идет именно о термине, связанном с архитектурой, то можно сказать: ***разрабатывать*** архитектуру.

Answer (score 1):

Такое словообразование возможно; значение глагола: "заниматься работой архитектора".

> Шестнадцать лет **архитекторствует** он там, забыв столичные соблазны,
>   квартиру, переживая тяготы быта. (Андрей Вознесенский, Стихи. Проза.
>   1987)

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно, словарный глагол от слова (или к слову) "архитектура" отсутствует.
Но есть словечки, которые (по принципу словообразования) правилам вроде бы и не противоречат. Назовём их неологизмами — а вдруг (как разговорные или специальные) когда-нибудь и войдут в язык?

Проект носит название [How to Architect](https://archspeech.com/article/arhitektor-sozdaet-slovar-arhitektury-v-15-sekundnyh-video), что можно перевести на русский язык конструкцией «Как **архитектурировать**». [*Фактура —* *фактурировать*]

– Архитектор! – улыбнулась мама.
– Знаете, почему я люблю **архитектировать**?  [*Корректура — корректировать*]
[В. Новая. Конструктор](http://httpwww.lio.ru/magazines/tropinka/2018/2/konstruktor-6709)

*...все второе десятилѣтіе своего **архитекторства** онъ заблуждался, что онъ не былъ истиннымъ художникомъ, строя семейные очаги...* [**архитекторствовать**]
М. О. Меньшиков. Критические очерки

Comment: Спасибо, это очень ценная информация.